# Jupyter notebook - rpy2 - Cannot find R libraries

Tags: python, r, jupyter-notebook, rpy2

I am currently trying to use both R and Python in the same Jupyter Notebook. I successfully installed rpy2; if I try to write something in R (putting `%%R` at the beginning) everything works, but as soon as I try to use a library, the following error appears:

> R[write to console]: Error in library(name of the package) : there is no package
> called - name of the package -

If I try to use the same library in R Studio (not in Jupyter) everything works.

This is the code is giving me trouble:

```
import os
os.environ['R_HOME'] = r'C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-40~1.0'
os.environ['path'] += r';C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-40~1.0\bin;'
%load_ext rpy2.ipython

%%R
library(readr)
```

After this last line the following error appears:

> R[write to console]: Error in library(readr) : there is no package called 'readr'
>
> Error in library(readr) : there is no package called 'readr'
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- RRuntimeError                             Traceback (most recent call
> last)
> ~\anaconda3\envs\Cattolica2020\lib\site-packages\rpy2\ipython\rmagic.py
> in eval(self, code)
> 267                 # Need the newline in case the last line in code is a comment.
> --> 268                 value, visible = ro.r("withVisible({%s\n})" % code)
> 269             except (ri.embedded.RRuntimeError, ValueError) as exception:
>
> ~\anaconda3\envs\Cattolica2020\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects_*init*_.py
> in **call**(self, string)
> 415         p = rinterface.parse(string)
> --> 416         res = self.eval(p)
> 417         return conversion.rpy2py(res)
>
> ~\anaconda3\envs\Cattolica2020\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\functions.py
> in **call**(self, *args, **kwargs)
> 196                 kwargs[r_k] = v
> --> 197         return (super(SignatureTranslatedFunction, self)
> 198                 .**call**(*args, **kwargs))
>
> ~\anaconda3\envs\Cattolica2020\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\functions.py
> in **call**(self, *args, **kwargs)
> 124                 new_kwargs[k] = conversion.py2rpy(v)
> --> 125         res = super(Function, self).**call**(*new_args, **new_kwargs)
> 126         res = conversion.rpy2py(res)
>
> ~\anaconda3\envs\Cattolica2020\lib\site-packages\rpy2\rinterface_lib\conversion.py
> in _(*args, **kwargs)
> 43     def _(*args, **kwargs):
> ---> 44         cdata = function(*args, **kwargs)
> 45         # TODO: test cdata is of the expected CType
>
> ~\anaconda3\envs\Cattolica2020\lib\site-packages\rpy2\rinterface.py in
> **call**(self, *args, **kwargs)
> 623             if error_occured[0]:
> --> 624                 raise embedded.RRuntimeError(_rinterface._geterrmessage())
> 625         return res
>
> RRuntimeError: Error in library(readr) : there is no package called
> 'readr'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> RInterpreterError                         Traceback (most recent call
> last)
> ~\anaconda3\envs\Cattolica2020\lib\site-packages\rpy2\ipython\rmagic.py
> in R(self, line, cell, local_ns)
> 762             else:
> --> 763                 text_result, result, visible = self.eval(code)
> 764                 text_output += text_result
>
> ~\anaconda3\envs\Cattolica2020\lib\site-packages\rpy2\ipython\rmagic.py
> in eval(self, code)
> 271                 warning_or_other_msg = self.flush()
> --> 272                 raise RInterpreterError(code, str(exception),
> 273                                         warning_or_other_msg)
>
> RInterpreterError: Failed to parse and evaluate line
> 'library(readr)\n'. R error message: "Error in library(readr) : there
> is no package called 'readr'"
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> PermissionError                           Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> ----> 1 get_ipython().run_cell_magic('R', '', 'library(readr)\n')
>
> ~\anaconda3\envs\Cattolica2020\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py
> in run_cell_magic(self, magic_name, line, cell)    2379
> with self.builtin_trap:    2380                 args = (magic_arg_s,
> cell)
> -> 2381                 result = fn(*args, **kwargs)    2382             return result    2383
>
> in R(self, line, cell, local_ns)
>
> ~\anaconda3\envs\Cattolica2020\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\magic.py
> in (f, *a, **k)
> 185     # but it's overkill for just that one bit of state.
> 186     def magic_deco(arg):
> --> 187         call = lambda f, *a, **k: f(*a, **k)
> 188
> 189         if callable(arg):
>
> ~\anaconda3\envs\Cattolica2020\lib\site-packages\rpy2\ipython\rmagic.py
> in R(self, line, cell, local_ns)
> 782                 print(e.err)
> 783             if tmpd:
> --> 784                 rmtree(tmpd)
> 785             return
> 786         finally:
>
> ~\anaconda3\envs\Cattolica2020\lib\shutil.py in rmtree(path,
> ignore_errors, onerror)
> 735             # can't continue even if onerror hook returns
> 736             return
> --> 737         return _rmtree_unsafe(path, onerror)
> 738
> 739 # Allow introspection of whether or not the hardening against symlink
>
> ~\anaconda3\envs\Cattolica2020\lib\shutil.py in _rmtree_unsafe(path,
> onerror)
> 613                 os.unlink(fullname)
> 614             except OSError:
> --> 615                 onerror(os.unlink, fullname, sys.exc_info())
> 616     try:
> 617         os.rmdir(path)
>
> ~\anaconda3\envs\Cattolica2020\lib\shutil.py in _rmtree_unsafe(path,
> onerror)
> 611         else:
> 612             try:
> --> 613                 os.unlink(fullname)
> 614             except OSError:
> 615                 onerror(os.unlink, fullname, sys.exc_info())
>
> PermissionError: [WinError 32] Impossibile accedere al file. Il file è
> utilizzato da un altro processo:
> 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp82eo8sb4\Rplots001.png'

I also tried to verify if the library directory is the same for Jupyter and R and I obtain the same two directories:

> [1] "C:/Users/User/Documents/R/win-library/4.0"
> [2] "C:/Program Files/R/R-4.0.0/library

I am currently using R 4.0.0 and Python 3.8.3

Answer (score 0):

The exception `RRuntimeError` is normally just forwarding to Python an exception that R generated itself during the execution.

The error message says that R does not find the library. If you are really sure that both RStudio and Jupyter use the very same R installed, the difference between the two will come from RStudio being instructed to look for installed R packages in more directories than the R started from Jupyter is.

Run the following in RStudio to know where `readr` is loaded from:

```
library(dplyr)
as_data_frame(installed.packages()) %>%
  filter(Package == "readr") %>%
  select(Package, LibPath)
```